# Python - Compiling C Extensions at Runtime

Tags: python, cextension

I have a C program written to do some heavy numerical work, and have been thinking about the best way to implement a Python interface to the code.

The difficulty is that my C application must be recompiled in order to change some parameters, parameters I would very much like the Python interface to be able to alter.

I am fairly new to C extensions, is there an established way to compile the extension (or part of it) at runtime? Say when they the **init**() method of my wrapper object is called?

I suppose I could pre-compile many versions of the package, but I feel this would get unwieldy very quickly.  Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: PS - For the purposes of this question, I'd like to take the design of the C code as fixed. It's inconvenient, but these choices were made  for performance reasons after benchmarking a few different strategies and for now are locked in. Given this structure, I'm curious as to the best way to construct a Python interface. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to recompile to change parameters? Why can't they be function parameters?

Comment: Several modules need to be picked at compile time, and there are some parameters (setting lengths of internal data structures mostly) that are #define'd in the headers. For now this is a behavior I'd like to keep.

Comment: I might not have enough context, but this sounds like bad design to me. If the internal data structures lengths need to be variable (depending on runtime values), then __make__ them variable: e.g. `char* someString` instead of `char someString[MAX_STRING_LEN]` (that would introduce allocating/deallocating memory). Otherwise, I think that on every machine you run your module(s) you would need (at least) a _C_ compiler.

Comment: I was really hoping to avoid a discussion about the design of the C code, which I'm not interested in modifying at this point. FWIW it's a fluid dynamics code written to be run on large clusters. During development it was found this design led to better performance. At this point I'm just trying to figure out if it's possible to write a wrapper for Python to interface with it.

Comment: Python can make an OS shell call to a script which does the compile. If you're talking #defines, that's easy to handle in a makefile, and easy to pass in by command line args or env variables. Are you more worried about how to unload/reload the module, or can you just have a different python program actually do the calculations?

Comment: I am worried about unloading/reloading the module. Doing the OS calls manually seemed pretty hacky, they should really be to the setup.py, yes? I guess I was hoping there was some built in way for a package basically to re-install itself at runtime.